# \thisfloatpagestyle{empty} is affecting all float pages

Tags: tables, floats, page-numbering

I currently have several tables that a very long and overlap the page number.  For this reason, I would like to remove the paper number from the page containing the long table.  To do this I have tried using `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` from the `floatpag` package.  The problem is that `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` is removing the page number from every float page, not just the ones containing long tables.

My code:

```
\begin{table}[!p]
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} %Adjusting rowheight
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
        BLAH & BLAH & BLAH\\
        \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
    \end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[] Note.--- BLAH BLAH BLAH
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

Let me know what additional information I need to provided to faciliate the answering of this question, I'm a latex newbie.

Comment: Can you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates this problem? I created on using `\documentclass{article}` and two `table`s. Removing `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` from the one `table` left the page number. They may be placed elsewhere on the page, but for that you can use `\thisfloatpagestyle{plain}` (say) to restore them in the `plain` page style position. Either way, we'd like to replicate your problem.